# Formula related to combinatorial number

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I got the following result from WolframAlpha. For positive integer $k$, $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2k} C_{2n}^{n-i} = 2^{2n-k-1}\left((2k-1)!!n^k+o(n^k)\right),$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2k-1} C_{2n}^{n-i} = \frac12 C_{2n}^{n-1}\left((k-1)!n^k+o(n^k)\right),$$
as $n \to\infty$.

I try for $k=1,\dots,10$, and it is correct. I'm wondering if there is proof of this.

Update: See the proof for $k=1$ in [prove a binomial identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611896/prove-a-binomial-identity-sum-i-1n-i-binom2nn-i-frac12n1-binom2) for both formulas.

Comment: Presumably $C_{2n}^{n-i}$ the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n-i}?$

Comment: Yes, it is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Some possible ideas: First, use the identity by @
Rezha Adrian Tanuharja, see the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614246/identity-for-difference-of-sum-of-products-of-binomial-coefficients. Second, the generating function of $i^m\binom{2n}{n-i}$ is $i^m\binom{0}{-i} _3 F_2(\frac12,1,1;1-i,1+i;4z)$ by WolframAlpha, and the partial sum of hypergeometric function may help to prove, see page 223 section 5.7 in the book: csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. These two equations have been well-studied in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606080.pdf. Both polynomials $P_k(n)$ and $Q_k(n)$ have explicit form.